# Regex, match everything except \r \n as normal character

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using regex in C# to getting filtered lines from a file. First I'm reading the whole .txt file into a string. In that case the code insert \r\n between the lines. But these are not special characters at the moment, just normaly strings. In one line the datas are separated by * char. My regex is looking for some value in some sepcial "cell" of a line, if it match, it must give back the whole line without \r\n at the begining and at the end.
Can yout take a look on my solution, and give me a tip, how to get matches without \r\n at the begining?

Thanks!

[Regex solution](https://regex101.com/r/COj8nM/1)

Comment: Can't you try the System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()  and process each line instead of reading the content as a whole string?

Comment: Thank for the tip, but iterate trought the lines is much more slower than the regex filtered the needed lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
(?<=\\r\\n|^(?!\\r\\n))[^*]*?[*](iLVL_DUMMY)[*](?:[^*]*?[*])+?(2020|2019)[^*]*?[*].*?(?=\\r\\n)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

you can add `[^\r\n]` to your regex's begin and end, like
`[^\\r\\n*]*?[*](iLVL_DUMMY)[*][^*]*?[*][^*]*?[*][^*]*?[*][^*]*?[*](2020|2019)[^*]*?[*].*?(?=\\r\\n)`

Comment: Hi youbl. thanks for the tip!

Thats what I tried, but my problem with it, if the first value (at to moment is 0.0000) contains r or n, the chars till r or n will not match. I'm looking for a solution where a  \ followed by r or n.

Comment: the first value start with char `r`? OK, the regex was `(?<=(^|\\r\\n)).*?[*](iLVL_DUMMY)[*][^*]*?[*][^*]*?[*][^*]*?[*][^*]*?[*](2020|2019)[^*]*?[*].*?(?=\\r\\n)`

Comment: Unfurtunatelly, this inforamation, is not known, r or n can be part of the string, but not neccesary. I've got the right solution from RK_15, thanks for your time!